# Button works only after second click

Tags: javascript

Close button which remove the elements from DOM, work only on the second click.

Here is HTML part of button: That is closeBtn.

```js
function removeHeader() {
  var list = document.getElementById("main");
  list.removeChild(list.childNodes[0]);
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div class="nanoSaturnBanner">
    <p>teteasdasdasdsadasds sad asdasdasdasdasdas</p>

    <div class="banner-buttons">
      <label class="showme">Ads by Google</label>
      <a class="infoLink" href="https://support.google.com/adsense/#topic=3373519" target="_blank">
        <i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i>
      </a>
      <div class="closeBtn" onclick="removeHeader()">
        closeBtn
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You're probably better off using css selector: `document.querySelector("#main > div.nanoSaturnBanner").remove()`

Comment: Was the answer helpful enough to solve your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `list.childNodes[1]` because the `list.childNodes[0]` represent the `#text` node that is the whitespaces after `<div id="main">`. So, in first click it was removing that node and in second click it was removing the actual node with `<div class="nanoSaturnBanner">`

```js
function removeHeader() {
   var list = document.getElementById("main");
   list.removeChild(list.childNodes[1]);
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
    <div class="nanoSaturnBanner">
        <p>teteasdasdasdsadasds sad asdasdasdasdasdas</p>

        <div class="banner-buttons">
            <label class="showme">Ads by Google</label>
            <a class="infoLink" href="https://support.google.com/adsense/#topic=3373519" target="_blank">
                <i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i>
            </a>
            <div class="closeBtn" onclick="removeHeader()">
                <i class="far fa-window-close">close</i>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

> **Note**: Whitespace inside elements is considered as text, and text is considered as nodes. Comments are also considered as nodes.

Answer (score 2):

As [`childNodes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes) get *none element nodes* as well, like *text* and *comment*, use e.g. [`children`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children) instead to get the first actual element.

*Note, with that you also make sure getting the element no matter how many* *"none element nodes"* *their might be in your markup.*

Stack snippet

```js
function removeHeader() {
   var list = document.getElementById("main");
   list.removeChild(list.children[0]);
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
    <div class="nanoSaturnBanner">
        <p>teteasdasdasdsadasds sad asdasdasdasdasdas</p>

        <div class="banner-buttons">
            <label class="showme">Ads by Google</label>
            <a class="infoLink" href="https://support.google.com/adsense/#topic=3373519" target="_blank">
                <i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i>
            </a>
            <div class="closeBtn" onclick="removeHeader()">
                <i class="far fa-window-close">close</i>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You could also be even more concise and use something like `list.querySelector(".nanoSaturnBanner")`. querySelector returns the first occurance of elements with class name "nanoSaturnBanner".

Comment: @schwaber Yes, if that element's class name will always be `.nanoSaturnBanner`. Grabbing `main` is safer being an `id` though (only occur once), and there is no performance gain using what you suggests either.

Comment: I *am* grabbing `#main` as I am refering to `list`. The whole point of using a selector is safety since other nodes might also occur before the `.nanoSaturnBurner` div. If the class name is subject to change it's probable it will also affect i.e. styling og the element. My guess is performance hardly is a potential issue here everything considered.

Comment: @schwaber Since no where OP mentioned there will be more element nodes before the one having `.nanoSaturnBurner`, there is no reason to give an answer that suggest how to overcome that. Also, `list.querySelector(".nanoSaturnBanner")` is no safer than any other way to select an element.

Comment: @schwaber And do note, I'm not saying using a selector is wrong.

Comment: You are right, maybe it is just down to personal preference. But personally I feel a tad bit uneasy removing nodes left and right. I prefer to have a named reference at the very least.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170601/discussion-between-schwaber-and-lgson).

Answer (score 0):

```
function removeHeader() {
   var list = document.getElementById("main");
   list.remove(list.childNodes[0]);  // replacing removeChild with remove worked
}
```

Check the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4bkapjto/).

Comment: That will remove the entire main div: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove